# Docker options for chaining dockerfiles

Tags: docker

I would love to make reusable dockerfiles. I don't see anyway to do this since there are no variables and no include option correct? Anyone have a good option (besides dyanmically creating / modifying the dockerfile and build time)?

Would love to be able to resuse production env dockerfiles since there is 1 per service (ex: 1 web app, 1 database, 1 cache, etc) and build all of them on the same image so I can run a full app in 1 container (1 possible use case is running multiple feature branches on a single server).

Yeah I know I could build each container separately and link them but seems like total over kill for setup and managing (since in some cases may need 6 or more containers for a single feature branch).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create multiple images you can always create a monster image with everything installed in it. In my opinion, that is a code smell, but it is possible. In case you will never split up the services across servers this might even be valid.

If you want to use the same kind of image in different contexts, you can use environment variables to parameterize behavior and still use the same image. For instance, have a bash script that expects YOUR_VARIABLE and the start your container using the `-e` option (see the [documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/run/#id19)). E.g.

```
docker run -e "YOUR_VARIABLE=value" --rm ubuntu env
```

Comment: that's a good point. 1 master image and then only run the service(s) required based on the environment. Definitely not ideal but does get the job done. Hopefully the INCLUDE option they have been talking about will make it in sooner rather than later

Comment: "1 master image and then only run the service(s) required based on the environment."  That is not my recommendation!  Only combine multiple services in an image if you will always use them together. Otherwise, make multiple images. Use environment variables to tweak behavior of a specific service using the image for that service in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools such as [fig](http://orchardup.github.io/fig/) that make bringing up a number of containers easy. You still get the separate systems that can be deployed individually, but they come up and are used as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags to name docker images. This makes it somewhat easy to chain dockerfile:

Assuming a directory `.` with sub-directories for modules `module1`, ...

build_all.sh:

```
docker build -t "module1" module1
docker build -t "module1" module2
```

If this is the sequenced used for building then in `module2/Dockerfile` you can use

```
FROM module1
```

Not perfect, because why would module2 need to know ahead of time about module1, but it works.